# ¿Cómo escribir correctamente el método click en PUPPETEER?

Tags: puppeteer

Muy buenas. Estoy intentando utilizar puppeteer para conseguir información de una web. En este caso usanddo el métoddo page.click. Necesito CLICKAR en el botón de búsquedda de la web:

https://eu.theory.com/homepage/?lang=en_BE

Me tira un error en node:

```
Error: No element found for selector: .search-btn button
```

El código que tengo es el siguiente. A ver si me podéis ayudar, por favor

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()

  //esta constante nos permite interactuar con las diferentes paginas
  const page = await browser.newPage();


  // el método goto NAVEGA hacia la página indicada
  await page.goto('https://eu.theory.com/homepage/?lang=en_BE');

  // el método screenshot saca captura de pantalla. Tienes que indicarle el path como se llamará el archivo


  await page.type('.search-field', 'trousers');
  // await page.screenshot({path: "captura3.jpg"});

  await page.click('.search-btn button');
  await page.screenshot({
    path: "captura4.jpg"
  });

  await browser.close();

})();
```

Comment: Tal vez necesites [`waitForSelector`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitforselector/) para que cargue todo el contenido dinámico antes de hacer click?

Comment: Gracias, conseguí hacerlo usando un selector distinto, desde CHROMIUM abriendo el inspector y usando el "copy selector". Ahora estoy atascado en sacar los enlaces / fotos / texto en un array...pero bueno, ya sería otra consulta jejej. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Para este caso que mencionas, la forma correcta sería que buscaras dentro de tu pagina web el id.

Ejemplo, suponiendo suponiendo que este es el elemento al que quieres hacer click

```html
<form id="search" class="s-topbar">
```

en este caso necesitas tomar el id que es "search" y hacer el click de la siguiente manera

```js
await page.click('search')
```

de esta manera podras hacer click donde necesites